# <tr> removing border on left and right only

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove these areas? (marked with black)

[image: a busy cat]

Here is my current CSS:

```
table.report { 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}

table.report td, table.report th { 
    border:1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
    padding:5px; 
}

tr.title {
    border-left: 0px solid;
    border-right: 0px solid;
}

td.normal {
    min-width: 200px;
}

td.extended {
    min-width: 400px;
}

p.center {
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="report">
    <tr class="title">
        <td colspan="4"><p class="center">Solution 1</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="normal">Assured Load</td>
        <td class="normal">{PHP Returns}</td>
        <td class="extended" colspan="2">{PHP Returns}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JqqmZ/)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The existing borders are applied to table cells, not rows, so setting row borders to 0px won't help. Apply the zero-border to cells instead:

```
tr.title td {
    border-left: 0px solid;
    border-right: 0px solid;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JqqmZ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/JqqmZ/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
tr.title td:first-child {
    border-left: 0 !important;
    border-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the styling into the `TD`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JqqmZ/1/)**

```
<td class="title" colspan="4"><p class="center">Solution 1</p></td>

tr td.title {
    border-left: 0px solid ;
    border-right: 0px solid ;
}
```

Comment: It works. But as soon as that is done, the entire row is not centered anymore. See attached image, (http://i.imgur.com/YGZkvAs.png)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative will be using white color for both the borders (in this way you can specify the left and right border color, e.g. to be red, but in this example it is white which effectively hides the borders)

```
.noleftnoright {
border-left:1px solid white;
border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

```css
.noleftnoright {
border-left:1px solid white;
border-right:1px solid white;
}

.maintable{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table  border=1 class=maintable>
<tr><td class=noleftnoright colspan=3>Line 1
<tr><td>A<td>B<td>C

<tr><td class=noleftnoright colspan=3>Line 2

</table>
```